# Deploy a web application for testing purposes to a tablet?

Tags: ipad, testing, mobile, netbeans

i am in the testing phase, and have created a web application (JSF) in netbeans, but need to test it on a tablet, what are my options for deploying it so i can try it on the tablet, if not is there any simulators i can use on the desktop ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what aspects of a tablet you are testing. Is it screen size? Just resize any webkit browser. Is it user agent detection? Chrome lets you change it, and so does Firefox. Is it touch support? Speed on mobile devices? You can always install the Android emulator and create a tablet device.

Mobile browsers are usually up to date with the desktop browsers, so you can count on them to be pretty accurate when it comes to rendering. For the rest, you will need to emulate, although performance is very restricted.

Comment: Thanks, i just wanted to make sure on an ipad it will work, everything can be selected, and it is the same user experience on a tablet as a desktop, so i suppose it is just will it work on the size screen a tablet has, will all the features work and is it still as effective

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are *really* talking about a web app, you don't want/need to *deploy* it on a tablet.  You actually want/need to test the web interface on a tablet.

And the best way to do that is to buy or borrow a tablet (e.g. an iPad), connect it to your network ... or wherever your web server is running ... start the tablet's web browser and load the server's URL.

You could also simulate it (sort of) with a desktop PC by reducing the browser window size to roughly the size of a table screen.  However, that is not likely to pick up any layout quirks etc of the actual tablet's web browser.